# Responding to ad placed by employer for position recuiter referred me to months ago

Tags: recruitment

I responded to an ad by a recuiter several months ago who sent me on an interview and it went very well and was told they would like to see me again.  When I followed up, I was told the company decided to recruit internally.  Not sure if that meant they were hiring from within or soliciting on their own.
Now, several months later,  I see that company place an ad on job site for the position.  Would it be underhanded if I apply?  On the one hand, yes, I know how it works with recruiters but this is some time later and I'm just replying to a public solicitation.

Comment: Why don't you call the company and inquire? (not the recruiter)

Answer (score 3):

Not underhanded at all so long as you don't have a contract in place where you only apply to jobs through that recruiter.  Their relationship with the recruiter may require them to pay if you are hired or may not.  That is not really any of your concern since it is between them.

Answer (score 1):

**You** owe the recruiter nothing, he/she did not find you a job you wanted, so your relationship ended.  **The company** may owe the recruiter his/her fee if you apply.

Some companies advertise through a recruiter, get qualified candidate, then place the same ad a few months later.  Depending on the contract with the recruiter, the company may still owe him/her a commission.  Ideally, this is something the company would have dealt with before reposting the position, but don't assume that.

**How this could affect you.**  Some companies do not understand they cannot hire someone a recruiter brought to them as a free agent without either 1) running out the contract OR 2) paying commission.

If the company starts the paper work, the recruiter may get wind they've hired you.  He/she will threaten legal action if you start work.  Now the company will delay hiring you for weeks or months while this is sorted out.  Worse the company could hire you, then put you on leave or terminate you if the recruiter threatens to sue (though they would still owe the commission, I believe).

**Bottom Line** - Its not at all underhanded for you, but may be underhanded by the company.

Comment: __Some companies do not understand they cannot hire someone a recruiter brought to them as a free agent without either 1) running out the contract OR 2) paying commission.__  In my experience, not all recruiters (at least in the US) have a legally binding contract with an employer.  Now that I think of it, that's the single most common thing recruiters have lied to me about; that they have an exclusive contract with a given company they have contacted me about.

Comment: Some recruiters do a bad job.  Good ones have legally binding contracts.  The OP could still end up in hot water if the company doesn't know what they're doing, and didn't read a the contract, which I've seen.